# How to use toFixed on JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having trouble trying to use toFixed to round up the numbers coming from my json response. I have tried multiple things but no dice. Here is the code im using:

```
var jsonData = '[{"rank":"9.8776580879","content":"Alon","UID":"5"},{"rank":"6.8787564934","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';

$.ajax({
url: '/echo/json/',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    json: jsonData
},
success: function (response) {
    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.rank.toFixed(2) + '</td><td>' + item.content + '</td><td>' + item.UID + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
}
```

});

```
<table id="records_table" border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>UID</th>
</tr>
```

Can you guys/girls take a look at JS Fiddle and let me know what i'm missing:

https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/tqyn3/1175/

Thanks alot

Comment: Where's the reference in your code to `toFixed`?

Comment: Sorry, i removed it to show the "working" code. I have added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to cast your strings to number and then use [Number.prototype.toFixed()](http://Number.prototype.toFixed()) on the number.

Something like `"9.4456"` is a string not a number due to the quotes

```
(+item.rank).toFixed(2)
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/okw9mzvd/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for that, I did all of that minus including the + inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
parseFloat(item.rank).toFixed(2)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tnpr5qq/